# How to extract only this value ? bs4+requests+pandas

Tags: python, parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

[image]

**How to extract only this value ?**

I have:
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from time import sleep
import pandas as pd

Comment: have you tried getting the item from the span `class job-card--meta-info-item`

Answer (score 0):

This would be one way:

```
magic_number = soup.select_one('span:-soup-contains("people_alt")').next_sibling
```

BeautifulSoup documentation can be found here: https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: I got only "\n" value. But I want to get value "1"

Comment: @VladyslavNazarov provide the url of the page, or the page' HTML, and I will debug it. The value you get means there is a newline in that element, so you may wanna get the next sibling to that newline (which should be the actual number).